# Performance optimization of practice program

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, performance, lambda

I am writing simple practice program in python. In few words, from given string is needed to split the input text using these separators:
`, ; : . ! ( ) " ' \ / [ ] space` into list of words. Then I need to print only lower-cases words, upper-cases words and mixed-cases words separated.

Here is my solution:

```
import re
import time

text = input()
start_time = time.time()

list_of_words = list(re.findall(r"[\w']+", text))

lower_cases_list = [word for word in list_of_words if word.islower()]
upper_cases_list = [word for word in list_of_words if word.isupper()]
mixed_cases_list = [word for word in list_of_words if not word.islower() and 
not word.isupper()]

print('Lower-case:', ', '.join(lower_cases_list))
print('Mixed-case:', ', '.join(upper_cases_list))
print('Upper-case:', ', '.join(mixed_cases_list))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

So far so good, It's works correctly, but in the platform that I am testing the task, the allowed execution time is 0.100 sec, in the best case my program is executed with time 0.134 s. Can anyone help me to optimize the code for best performance?

Comment: put it in a function to prevent global variable lookups, only loop through tthe list once (thus obviating the need to create a list from re.findall).

Comment: why do you need to do with list comprehension. You can iterate in single loop and assign to the list where condition is satisfied. reducing time complexity of 3n -> n

Comment: So list comprehension is not the fastest approach? I will loop trough regular loops then, and see whats happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems build-in lib **re** is slower than regular methods like **.replace()** and **.split()**

With this code:

```
def h(txt):
    txt = txt.replace(',', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace(';', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace(':', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace('.', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace('!', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace('(', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace(')', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace('"', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace('\'', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace('\\', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace('/', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace('[', r' ')
    txt = txt.replace(']', r' ')

    return txt


def do_all(list_of_words):
    lower_cases_list = []
    upper_cases_list = []
    mixed_cases_list = []

    for word in list_of_words:
        if word.islower():
            lower_cases_list.append(word)
        elif word.isupper():
            upper_cases_list.append(word)
        else:
            mixed_cases_list.append(word)

    print('Lower-case:', ', '.join(lower_cases_list))
    print('Mixed-case:', ', '.join(mixed_cases_list))
    print('Upper-case:', ', '.join(upper_cases_list))

text = h(input()).split()

do_all(text)
```

Execution time is < 0.50 ms. So The problem solved. **.split()** and **.replace** is faster than **re**

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over your words three times. Do it once with a single for loop:

```
for word in list_of_words:

    if word.islower():
        lower_cases_list.append(word)
    elif word.isupper():
        upper_cases_list.append(word)
    else:
        mixed.append(word)
```

Additionally since now you're only iterating over your `list_of_words` once, you don't actually have to make a list and can just use a generator, saving a little bit more time:

```
list_of_words = re.findall(r"[\w']+", text)
```

Comment: Any ideas for faster alternative of  re.findall(r"[\w']+", text) ?